# Javascript and html from php with spaces

Tags: javascript, php

I am writing javascript and html from php, and I have a problem when setting the atributte *value* of the tag *option*. The problem is when the variable $txt has a word with spaces, e.g *La Libertad* the attribute value shows value="La" libertad. Do you help me plase how to fix this problem?. Below my code

```
"<option SELECTED value=\"$txt\">$txt</option>"
```

Comment: try this. "<option SELECTED value=".$txt.">".$txt."</option>";

Comment: tried it in phpfiddle nad seems to work for me.. I guess you need to post more code

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong (or obviously JavaScript (it appears to be pure PHP), for that matter) with that code. You'll need to provide more context. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you add single quote to the value. I feel you using nested double quote could be a cause. Try something like this:

```
echo "$(\"#$target_javascript\").append(\"
value=\'+array_list[i].value+\'>\"+array_list[i].display+\"\");\r";
```

I think it should work well with single quote....

Something Like this:

```
echo "<option SELECTED value='".$txt."'>$txt</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this too:

```
<?php echo '<option SELECTED value="'.$txt.'">'.$txt.'</option>'; ?>
```